# How to fail when maven profile does not exist?

Tags: maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I have a few maven profiles in my pom.xml. I have jenkins configured to run nightly tests for each of these profiles.

I figured today that there was a spelling mistake in one of the profile names in my jenkins config. Turns out that if maven cannot file a profile, it runs the default profile.

Is there a way I can force maven to throw an error if the profile doesn't exist?

Answer (score 6):

Maven Enforcer Plugin version 3.0.0-M2 has introduced a built-in check [**requireProfileIdsExist**](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProfileIdsExist.html) for this purpose:

> When running Maven with one or more **unknown profile ids,** Maven will give you a warning. **This rule will actually break the build for that reason.**
>
> Here is how a project should be setup to use this rule
>
> ```
> <project>
> ...
>   <build>
>     <plugins>
>       ...
>       <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>         <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
>         <executions>
>           <execution>
>             <id>enforce</id>
>             <configuration>
>               <rules>
>                 <requireProfileIdsExist/>
>               </rules>
>             </configuration>
>             <goals>
>               <goal>enforce</goal>
>             </goals>
>           </execution>
>         </executions>
>       </plugin>
>       ...
>     </plugins>
>   </build>
>   ...
> </project>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Maven Enforcer Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a profile exists without configuring Maven Enforcer Plugin in the pom.xml:

```
> mvn enforcer:enforce -Denforcer.rules=requireProfileIdsExist -PprofileToCheck
...
[WARNING] The requested profile "profileToCheck" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0:enforce (default-cli) on project idegen: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
```